# React-Native Splash screen fake

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, splash-screen, fadeout

I have a "animated" Splash screen with Lottie which looks identically to the iOS "native" Splash screen, I created in Xcode. Now I want to first launch the "native" Splash screen and then my "animated" one. The transition has to be seamless, so the user doesn't recognize, that it first was an image.

BUT

the "native" screen fades out and then my "fake screen" opens. `So I want to get rid of the "fade out" between the screens`. Any ideas or other approaches? Thank you so much!

Comment: are you using react navigation? you have to disable their animation

Comment: yes @user8119020 - how to disable the fade in after splash screen?   Probablyy not with options={{
        animationEnabled: false,
      }}

Comment: But it's probably due to native code and not React navigation I think?